# Is there any algorithm with the time complexity of O(n*(log n)^2)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

I know that [heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) has a time complexity of *O(n log n)*, but I can't really think of an algorithm that has one of *O(n (log n)<sup>2</sup>)*.

Comment: The answer is a definite yes. It's easy to construct such an algorithm. If you want to find one that is already being used for something, that's a different matter. You should think about what the numbers could mean: `n*` means you need to do something for every element of the input set, `log n` means some kind of divide and conquer operation, and squared means that you probably need another divide and conquer for every step of the previous one.

Comment: `O(n * log n)` is a subset of `O(n * (log n)^2)`, so every algorithm with a time complexity of `O(n * log n)` also has a time complexity of `O(n * (log n)^2)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is super easy to construct one. The most obvious example is:

```
for i in xrange(n * int(log(n, 2) ** 2)):
   // do something O(1)
```

For a more helpful example you can use [Master's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) to come up with infinite amount of recursions that satisfy your needs (any `k` will work):

[image]

---

If you are looking for a real algorithm, then [Shellsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort) has a worst case complexity of *O(n (log n)<sup>2</sup>)*. The same for an [inplace mergesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Variants).

**P.S.** a fancy name for the stuff you are looking for is quasilinear time complexity with k = 2.

Answer (score 2):

A classic (and most practical) example is [stable_sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) of STL. The log-quadratic factor comes due to the merge stage itself being recursive (which allows the entire algorithm to run in-place).

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamization tends to increase complexity by a factor of log n, so the if you do n queries of the dynamized version of a data structure with underlying cost log n, you will get n log(n)^2